# NoReverseMatch Django URL

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I always get this error when try to use url tag:

```
    Reverse for 'show' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments 
    '{}' not   found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['app/$show/']
```

my url tag:

```
    <a href="{% url 'show' %}"> item </a>
```

url.py

```
    url(r'^app/$', include('app.urls')),
```

app.url.py

```
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.index', name='app_index'),
    url(r'^show/', 'app.views.show', name='show'),
```

What can be wrong? Been following the Django doucmentation and searched around the internet with no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you've included the $ in the regex that matches an include, you should remove this

```
url(r'^app/', include('app.urls')),
```

and add it to the end of show

```
 url(r'^show/$', 'app.views.show', name='show'),
```

The `$` in a regex indicates the end of a line, which obviously isn't the case when you're intending to build upon it with an include.